# Passing data through props with react+ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax-error

Im trying to do the quick start tutorial from here: https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe in ts instead of js.
whats wrong? it says:
'number' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Binding element 'number' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

```
export default function Board(){
  return (
    <>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={1}/>
        <Square value={2}/>
        <Square value={3}/> 
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={4}/>
        <Square value={5}/>
        <Square value={6}/>
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={7}/>
        <Square value={8}/>
        <Square value={9}/>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function Square({value: number}){
  return <button className="square">{value}</button>;
}
```

it says:
'number' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Binding element 'number' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(703

Comment: Be careful for fuctional component, your `Square` component should be like: `function Square(props: {value: number}) { ... }`

Comment: Should be `{ value }: { value: number }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
function Square({value: number}) {
  // ...
}
// is equivalent to:
function Square({ value: number }: any) {
  // ...
}
// or
function Square(props: any) {
  const number = props.value;

  // ...
}


// what you want is providing the type for the props:
function Square({ value }: { value: number }) {
 // ...
}

// or
interface SquareProps {
  value: number;
}

function Square({ value }: SquareProps) {
 // ...
}

// which is equivalent to:
function Square(props: SquareProps) {
 const value = props.value;
 // ...
}
```

Good luck with your learning journey!